# How I can open the Local files(xls, docs) in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, file, dart, xls, doc

I have to open local Xls and docs files in my flutter app. Currently, I already displayed pdf & image files but facing issues while opening the xls and docs.

Help me out to open these files in the app itself.